# Distinct, order in 1 query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `downloads` table that records each time a user downloads a file. I want to write a query that returns the most recent x downloads, but show a user at most just once. For instance, say this is the order in which a file was downloaded, and I want to retrieve the most recent 2 downloads:

```
// Downloads table
1. Steve - 12:01am
2. James - 12:02am
3. John  - 12:03am
4. Steve - 12:04am
5. Steve - 12:05am

select distinct(username), created_at 
from downloads 
group by username, created_at 
order by created_at desc limit 2

// Result SHOULD be
Steve - 12:05am
John  - 12:03am
```

Is this correct? Is there a way to this query in with ActiveRecord without using a custom query?

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to order by `max(created_at)` since you want the most recent download by user

```
select username, max(created_at)
from downloads
group by username
order by max(created_at) desc
limit 2
```

`username` will already be unique because you're grouping by that column, so no need to use `distinct`

active record

```
Downloads
 .select("max(created_at),username")
 .group("username")
 .order("max(created_at) desc")
 .limit(2);
```